# FastSineTransformer - pad array with zeros to fit length

Tags: java, math, poisson, apache-commons-math

I'm trying to implement a poisson solver for image blending in **Java**. After descretization with 5-star method, the real work begins.
To do that i do these three steps with the color values:

1. using sine transformation on rows and columns
2. multiply eigenvalues
3. using inverse sine transformation on rows an columns

This works so far.
To do the sine transformation in Java, i'm using the Apache Commons Math package.

But the [FastSineTransformer](http://ommons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/transform/FastSineTransformer.html) has two limitations:

1. first value in the array must be zero (well that's ok, number two is the real problem)
2. the length of the input must be a **power of two**

So right now my excerpts are of the length 127, 255 and so on to fit in. (i'm inserting a zero in the beginning, so that 1 and 2 are fulfilled) That's pretty stupid, because i want to choose the size of my excerpt freely.

My Question is:
**Is there a way to extend my array e.g. of length 100 to fit the limitations of the Apache FastSineTransformer?**

In the FastFourierTransfomer class it is mentioned, that you can pad with zeros to get a power of two. But when i do that, i get wrong results. Perhaps i'm doing it wrong, but i really don't know if there is anything i have to keep in mind, when i'm padding with zeros

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from http://books.google.de/books?id=cOA-vwKIffkC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q&f=false and the sources http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.2/org/apache/commons/math3/transform/FastSineTransformer.java?av=f

The rules are as follows:

- According to implementation the dataset size should be a power of 2 - presumable in order for algorithm to guarantee O(n*log(n)) execution time.
- According to James S. Walker function must be odd, that is the mentioned assumptions must be fullfiled and implementation trusts with that.
- According to implementation for some reason the first and the middle element must be 0:
  x'[0] = x[0] = 0,
  x'[k] = x[k] if 1 <= k < N,
  x'[N] = 0,
  x'[k] = -x[2N-k] if N + 1 <= k < 2N.

As for your case when you may have a dataset which is not a power of two I suggest that you can resize and pad the gaps with zeroes with not violating the rules from the above. But I suggest referring to the book first.